# Returns wrong answer

Tags: c

When I run this code, it iterates, but then returns "The answer is 0", when it should be "The answer is 10."

Why is this?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
     int i;
     for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++){ 
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            continue;
         }
         printf("Checking i = %d\n", i);
         if (i + 90 == i * i) {
             break;
         }
     }
    printf("The answer is %d.\n", i);
    return 0;


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two separate `i`s in your code, the inner one hiding the outer one. Moreover, the print statement causes undefined behaviour, because the outer `i` is read uninitialized.

Say `for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)` to use the outer variable instead of declaring a new variable.

Answer (score 8):

```
 int i;
 for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++){ 
      ^^^^^
```

The `i` inside the loop is not the same as the `i` outside the loop.

Repace that with:

```
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i < 12; i++){
```

Answer (score 1):

You're actually declaring `i` again inside the `for` loop. Make your for loop like so:

`for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)`

Then, it will retain its value once you exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are two seperate declared `int i`'s in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use i outside the for loop, **do not declare it inside for loop**

So your for loop should be like

```
for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
```